# call Synchronized inside another Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

**Part 1:**

Assume the following piece of code

```
void method1(){

    synchronized (lockObject){
        method2();
        System.out.println("line4");
    }

}

void method2(){
    System.out.println("line1");

    synchronized (lockObject){
        System.out.println("line2");
    }

    System.out.println("line3");
}
```

Is this a deadlock? Is it a safe code? Will the output always be:

```
line1
line2 
line3
line4
```

**Part 2:**

What if the method2() is executed on another thread? Will the output be different? Like this:

```
void method1(){

    synchronized (lockObject){
        method2();
        System.out.println("line4");
    }

}

void method2(){
        newThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {     
                System.out.println("line1");
                synchronized (lockObject){
                    System.out.println("line2");
                }
                System.out.println("line3");
            }
        }).start();
}
```

I am guessing the output of this second code can be:

```
line4
line1 
line2
line3
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I tried and observed some results... But computer science is not an experiment based science! If you do an test for 1000 times and you get the same result you cannot say that result is valid if you don't know what the underlying code is actually doing.

Comment: @Kasra you are 100% right, testing does not prove anything with multithreading issues, as the result will depend on execution order and you may get lucky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can synchronize multiple times on the same object without deadlock, it works like reentrant lock.

As for the output. The first is simple sequential output, and synchronization does not affect it. The second one will produce the expected output, as the other thread will have to wait for the first one to release the lockObject.

EDIT, the order of line1 and line4 is not determined, as there is no synchronization before. The line2 and line3 are always after line4 though as the second thread cannot start printing line1 until the first one leaves the method1 synchronization block.

Answer (score 4):

Part 1: No, there's no deadlock, because there's only one lock. Deadlock happens when multiple locks can be acquired in different orders. The output will always be the same.

Part 2: There will be no deadlock, but the order that the statements are printed can vary. Lines 1–3 will always appear in the correct order with respect to each other, but the "line4" statement can be printed before line 1 or line 2.

If you want to prevent line 4 from occurring between lines 1 and 2, you'd need to make them appear as an "atomic" operation by moving them inside the `synchronized` block.

Comment: It seems we disaggree again. To have the line4 printed anywhere, the execution of the first synchronized block would have to be interrupted, which synchronization is meant to prevent in the first place

Comment: I think line4 can be printed anywhere because the lock in method2 only applies to line2. The other lines (line1 and line3) are outside of the synchronized block.

Comment: Appologies, @erickson is right, the line1 is printed outside the synchrnoziation block.

Comment: You are right, it did not read the code carefully. but line4 cannot appear anywhere, only before or after line1.

Comment: @Zielu I went back to my original thinking. Lines 1–3 are not atomic, so line 4 can occur anywhere.

Comment: Second thread cannot print line2 before the first one leaves its synchronization block, so the line4 has to be always before line2.

Answer (score 2):

Intrinsic locks are reentrant. A thread can acquire one even if it already has possession of it.

From [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread. But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns. Allowing a thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code, directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block.

For your second example, the new thread you start will have to wait until the lock is released by the call to method1. It's likely the call to method1 will complete, freeing up the lock, before the new thread starts, because starting a new thread takes a while, but it isn't guaranteed. "line1" could be printed before "line4". For "line2" to get printed the method1 call has to have completed first.